# React mapping not splitting array when returning

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, jsx

I'm attempting to render errors when submitting a form using React (jsx files). In my form component, I render an error message as part of the component:

```
...
            <ul>Error: {props.errors.map((err, idx) => <li key={idx}>{err}</li>)}</ul>
...
```

However, even though my props.errors is an array composed of two strings ["Title cannot be blank", "Body cannot be blank"], the resulting list is only composed of one item joining both of these errors together without a comma ("Title cannot be blankBody cannot be blank).

I've additionally tried joining the two together using Array.join(", "), but this also would not add the space in-between the errors. Does anyone have an idea of why several items are being returned/rendered as a single item in React?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error array is actually a nested array, even though the Chrome console only shows it as a singular array. To solve this, therefore, I had to call `props.errors[0].map` if the array has a length greater than 0, then map through it.